# Sitecore Powershell Extensions for Sitecore 9.2

Tags: sxa, powershell-extensions

I ran into a problem installing SXA (Sitecore Experience Accelerator) 1.8 on a new Sitecore 9.2 instance. The problem is with SPE. The latest version of SPE on Marketplace is 5.0

Answer (score 3):

Sitecore 9.2 requires Sitecore Experience Accelerator (SXA) 1.9, not 1.8.

SXA 1.9 for Sitecore 9.2 requires either:

- The official Sitecore Powershell Extensions 5.1 version:    https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/releases/tag/5.1
- The SXA build of Sitecore Powershell Extensions 5.0 for Sitecore 9.2: https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Accelerator/19/Sitecore_Experience_Accelerator_190.aspx

Answer (score 1):

SXA 1.8 requires SPE 5.1, which as of right now is not available on Marketplace. If you're installing SXA 1.8 on 9.2, **download SPE 5.1 from GitHub**  https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/releases/tag/5.1.

Answer (score 0):

SPE is also available on the download site from Sitecore itself ;)

You can find it on the list of downloads for SXA 1.9:
https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Accelerator/19/Sitecore_Experience_Accelerator_190.aspx

Two versions are available there:

- Sitecore PowerShell Extension 5.0 for Sitecore 9.1
- Sitecore PowerShell Extension 5.0 for Sitecore 9.2

That is not yet the 5.1 version - but according to the install guides for SXA, SPE 5.0 should be sufficient.